# jquery autocomplete with checkboxes removing as search

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

On a page I have a search (input) box and below a few checkboxes with labels.

The idea is as people type the variable projects are searched and the results in the list are replaced with the result. this would probably mean losing the whole list and re-writing it

here is the js i am using

```
    var projects = [{   

    value: "open",
    label: "Open",
    },{
    value: "inprogress",
    label: "In Progress",
    },{
    value: "reopened",
    label: "Reopened",
    },{
    value: "closed",
    label: "Closed",
    },{
    value: "another",
    label: "Another Status",
    }];

    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: projects
    });

});
```

and here is the HTML

```
<form action="#" id="issue-filter">
<input  placeholder="Search..."  id="search" autocomplete="off" ><span class="icon noloading">More</span></div>
    <div id="searcher-status-suggestions" class="aui-list" style="display: block;">
        <div tabindex="-1" class="aui-list-scroll">
            <ul class="aui-last">
<li><input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" value="open">Open</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" value="inprogress">In Progress</li>                    
<li><input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" value="reopened">Re-Opened</li>      
<li><input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" value="inprogress">In Progress</li>  
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

i have setup the jquery ui, jquery etc and when i type into the input box I can see the list from the projects. I am not sure how to update the ul list as I type. Also the ul list might not have all the projects as it might show only the first 10

I have had a look at the jQuery documentation but am unsure of the best way to pull this off

Can anyone help?

an example fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/dwhitmarsh/CmYeq/

Comment: You mean the items from the checklist will be removed as people type their names in the textbox?

Comment: Do you mean something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q6KE5/

Comment: i guess what i am really trying to do is completly re-write the list result (ie check boxes) when a search is done